# Google Places - unexpected 50-char place_id values returned

Tags: google-places-api, google-geocoding-api, google-distancematrix-api

I am using the Google Geocoding API to retrieve place_id (and other) information to use with the Places API. Most addresses return an expected 27-character place_id value, i.e.:

```
ChIJUXJ61wrsFogR3jv6yBBFlQY
```

However, a small percentage of addresses which otherwise return seemingly good data (`formatted_address`, etc.) are returning 50-character values with the prefix `E` like:

```
EjA1Mjk1IFB1bGxleWJsYW5rIFN0LCBXaW5kc29yLCBPTiBOOU
```

These 50-char place_ids throw errors on Google's other APIs (i.e. Distance Matrix using the place_id as origin and/or destination):

```
Invalid request. Invalid 'origins' parameter. 'EiU5MDAxIFJpbGV5IFN0LCBaZWVsYW5kLCBNSSA0OTQ2NCwgVV' 
is not a valid Place ID.
```

When I look at Google's responses, I see they all fall into three categories:

1. location_type=RANGE_INTERPOLATED, types=street_address
2. location_type=ROOFTOP, types=subpremise
3. location_type=APPROXIMATE, types=intersection

All three indicate addresses with "issues" in some way (bogus street number, subsection of larger area, approximate location). So, I guess my question is:

***Are 50-character place_id values always garbage?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're truncating these IDs, so that's why the API says they are invalid.  They can be more than 50 characters.

If you keep the whole ID intact they `E` prefix IDs will work with Distance Matrix etc.

Comment: Do not impose your own size limits on Place IDs, they can be arbitrarily long.

Comment: So, this seems like a bad question now - clearly a simple mistake on my part. Should I just delete this question?

Comment: No, it is a good question, because https://developers.google.com/places/place-id looks like Place IDs are expected to always be 27-character strings.